# Android: key even listener isn't called

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to catch the keyboard events on this EditText:

```
 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/deal_edit_name"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:ems="10" >
```

This is the code I´m using:

```
EditText nameEdit = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.deal_edit_name);
nameEdit.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.d("hello",keyCode+" "+ v.toString()+" "+ event.toString());
            return false;
     }
});
```

However when I click any key (keyboard or hardware) nothing is shown in my LogCat. What is wrong here?

Comment: the edittext have the focus when a key/something else is clicked?

Comment: Yes, I'm typing in the edit text and nothing happens.

Comment: Do you test this with soft(vitual) keyboard or hardware keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like that :
You have to return true to get the event

```
EditText nameEdit = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.deal_edit_name);
nameEdit.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {           
         @Override
         public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
               switch (keyCode)
               {
                  case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                        // do something
                        return true;
                  default:
                        break;
               }
            }
       }
 });
```

Comment: The key listener only registers volume up/down hardware keys. Nothing else.

Comment: What do you mean ? You want to get event from the screen or from the volume button ? I don't really understand what you want to do.

Comment: I want to listen for the "enter" keyboard event. The only event that this method records is the up/down volume, which frankly is quite useless.

Comment: Did you read the documentation here : https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands.html maybe this is what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) || (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
                Log.i(TAG,"Enter pressed");
            }  
                else   
                Log.i(TAG,"button pressed");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: That's not going to work because I need to listen for the Enter key.

Comment: Still doesn't work. It listens to when I change the volume but not when I click anything else.

Comment: try to catch the done event with my new edited code or others.